# Problem with 'find' method (BeautifulSoup) when parsing xml webpage

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup

I’m trying to extract some XML data from WASDE (“World Agricultural Supply and Demand Estimates) webpage using BeautifulSoup and using the ‘find’ method and ‘lxml’ parser but I have an error and I cannot find a solution.
See the code below.

Data1, Data2 and Data4 are exactly in the same path. I can extract Data1 and Data2 but python gives me an attribute error on Data4: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'cell'`.

The only difference I found is that the attribute1 of Data1 and Data2 are single words “Production” (Data1) and “Imports” (Data2), nevertheless, the attribute1 of Data4 is composed of two separated words “Ending Stocks”. This seems to be the problem because if you replace “Ending Stocks” with “Domestic Feed” which is in the same path, you will find the same error but if you replace it with “Exports” which is also in the same path, the code will work fine.

But if you look now to Data3, which is in a different path but has a long attribute1 “Yield per Harvested Acre”, the code will work fine.
So, the question is: Why ‘find’ method of Beutifulsoup doesn’t work sometimes when there is more than one word in an attribute? Any solution or better coding for this?

```
# Import libraries to be used
from urllib.request import urlopen
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# URL to be parsed
URL = 'https://www.usda.gov/oce/commodity/wasde/wasde1119.xml'

# Downloading URL and creating BeautifulSoup object
html = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")

# Get Data1 and print it
Data1 = soup.sr19.matrix1.find("m1_month_group",{"forecast_month1" :"Oct"}).find("m1_attribute_group",{"attribute1": "Production"}).cell["cell_value1"]
print("Data1 =  ", Data1)

# Get Data2 and print it
Data2 = soup.sr19.matrix1.find("m1_month_group",{"forecast_month1" :"Oct"}).find("m1_attribute_group",{"attribute1": "Imports"}).cell["cell_value1"]
print("Data2=  ", Data2)

# Get Data3 and print it
Data3 = soup.sr11.matrix1.find("attribute1",{"attribute1":"Yield per Harvested Acre"}).find("m1_month_group",{"forecast_month1": "Nov"}).cell["cell_value1"]
print("Data3=  ", Data3)

# Get Data4 and print it
Data4 = soup.sr19.matrix1.find("m1_month_group",{"forecast_month1" :"Oct"}).find("m1_attribute_group",{"attribute1": "Ending Stocks"}).cell["cell_value1"]
print("Data4=  ", Data4)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


r = requests.get(
    'https://www.usda.gov/oce/commodity/wasde/wasde1119.xml')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')

production = []
imports = []
nov = []
stock = []

for item in soup.findAll('m1_attribute_group', attrs={'attribute1': 'Production'}):
    for cell in item.findAll('cell'):
        cell = cell.get('cell_value1')
        if cell is not None:
            production.append(cell)
for item in soup.findAll('m1_attribute_group', attrs={'attribute1': 'Imports'}):
    for cell in item.findAll('cell'):
        cell = cell.get('cell_value1')
        if cell is not None:
            imports.append(cell)
for item in soup.findAll('m1_month_group', attrs={'forecast_month1': 'Nov'}):
    for cell in item.findAll('cell'):
        cell = cell.get('cell_value1')
        if cell is not None:
            nov.append(cell)
for item in soup.findAll('m1_attribute_group'):
    for cell in item.findAll('cell', attrs={'cell_value1': True}):
        cell = cell.get('cell_value1')
        if cell is not None:
            stock.append(cell)

for a, b, c, d in zip(production, imports, nov, stock):
    print(
        "Production: {:<10}  Imports: {:<10}  Nov: {:<10}  Stock: {:<10}".format(a, b, c, d))
```

Output:

```
Production: 762.31      Imports: 180.03      Nov: 2658.19     Stock: 2618.41   
Production: 627.98      Imports: 176.09      Nov: 3456.69     Stock: 3416.96   
Production: 47.38       Imports: 4.30        Nov: 428.02      Stock: 414.83      
Production: 714.93      Imports: 175.72      Nov: 2664.54     Stock: 2600.42     
Production: 333.09      Imports: 6.96        Nov: 792.15      Stock: 816.54    
Production: 18.50       Imports: 0.01        Nov: 765.55      Stock: 2629.43     
Production: 20.94       Imports: 0.16        Nov: 1043.45     Stock: 3445.97     
Production: 30.38       Imports: 0.45        Nov: 180.68      Stock: 428.40      
Production: 151.13      Imports: 5.82        Nov: 755.17      Stock: 2647.47     
Production: 85.17       Imports: 0.47        Nov: 288.28      Stock: 798.49      
Production: 26.98       Imports: 0.06        Nov: 1394.89     Stock: 2659.68     
Production: 202.93      Imports: 115.67      Nov: 1742.19     Stock: 3460.07     
Production: 1.15        Imports: 6.15        Nov: 201.56      Stock: 426.56      
Production: 4.26        Imports: 7.02        Nov: 1415.37     Stock: 2663.17     
Production: 134.33      Imports: 3.94        Nov: 326.83      Stock: 796.90      
Production: 0.97        Imports: 5.88        Nov: 497.76      Stock: 2658.19     
Production: 19.25       Imports: 27.45       Nov: 671.05      Stock: 3456.69     
Production: 0.07        Imports: 5.16        Nov: 45.78       Stock: 428.02      
Production: 18.36       Imports: 18.46       Nov: 494.01      Stock: 2664.54     
Production: 0.00        Imports: 26.06       Nov: 177.04      Stock: 792.15      
Production: 98.51       Imports: 1.17        Nov: 2,239.15    Stock: 762.31      
Production: 14.80       Imports: 0.10        Nov: 2,941.47    Stock: 1025.03     
Production: 765.23      Imports: 175.68      Nov: 349.26      Stock: 182.47      
Production: 765.55      Imports: 176.53      Nov: 2,309.22    Stock: 742.31      
Production: 633.23      Imports: 172.48      Nov: 711.00      Stock: 282.73      
Production: 633.55      Imports: 173.33      Nov: 713.29      Stock: 731.28      
Production: 53.39       Imports: 3.27        Nov: 958.54      Stock: 1014.01     
Production: 52.26       Imports: 3.27        Nov: 154.82      Stock: 172.89      
Production: 711.84      Imports: 172.41      Nov: 723.71      Stock: 736.11      
Production: 713.29      Imports: 173.27      Nov: 260.68      Stock: 277.90      
Production: 324.70      Imports: 6.66        Nov: 1,034.06    Stock: 765.23      
Production: 326.20      Imports: 6.66        Nov: 1,320.21    Stock: 1042.91     
Production: 20.50       Imports: 0.01        Nov: 151.67      Stock: 179.68    
Production: 20.00       Imports: 0.01        Nov: 1,095.67    Stock: 755.11      
Production: 18.00       Imports: 0.15        Nov: 274.43      Stock: 287.80      
Production: 17.20       Imports: 0.15        Nov: 491.79      Stock: 765.55      
Production: 33.00       Imports: 0.45        Nov: 662.72      Stock: 1043.45     
Production: 33.00       Imports: 0.45        Nov: 42.76       Stock: 180.68      
Production: 152.00      Imports: 5.50        Nov: 489.85      Stock: 755.17      
Production: 153.00      Imports: 5.50        Nov: 175.89      Stock: 288.28    
Production: 72.50       Imports: 0.48        Nov: 571.30      Stock: 1361.22     
Production: 74.00       Imports: 0.48        Nov: 699.06      Stock: 1747.20     
Production: 28.70       Imports: 0.08        Nov: 172.55      Stock: 185.23    
Production: 29.00       Imports: 0.08        Nov: 494.66      Stock: 1375.95     
Production: 203.07      Imports: 114.99      Nov: 109.99      Stock: 371.25      
Production: 203.29      Imports: 115.49      Nov: 337.76      Stock: 1398.80     
Production: 1.10        Imports: 6.00        Nov: 352.64      Stock: 1770.05     
Production: 1.10        Imports: 6.00        Nov: 93.64       Stock: 211.36      
Production: 5.30        Imports: 7.70        Nov: 336.39      Stock: 1422.75     
Production: 5.30        Imports: 7.70        Nov: 13.79       Stock: 347.30      
Production: 132.00      Imports: 3.20        Nov: 206.47      Stock: 1396.68     
Production: 132.00      Imports: 3.20        Nov: 227.55      Stock: 1747.53     
Production: 0.95        Imports: 5.90        Nov: 88.69       Stock: 201.01      
Production: 0.95        Imports: 5.90        Nov: 204.54      Stock: 1413.52     
Production: 18.87       Imports: 27.40       Nov: 19.09       Stock: 334.01      
Production: 18.87       Imports: 27.40       Nov: 45.2        Stock: 1394.89     
Production: 0.06        Imports: 5.10        Nov: 37.2        Stock: 1742.19     
Production: 0.06        Imports: 5.10        Nov: 51.7        Stock: 201.56      
Production: 22.46       Imports: 17.29       Nov: 1,080       Stock: 1415.37     
Production: 22.68       Imports: 17.09       Nov: 1,920       Stock: 326.83    
Production: 0.00        Imports: 27.10       Nov: 120         Stock: 494.88      
Production: 0.00        Imports: 27.10       Nov: 3,120       Stock: 644.73      
Production: 102.19      Imports: 0.02        Nov: 955         Stock: 47.13       
Production: 102.19      Imports: 0.02        Nov: 61          Stock: 482.17      
Production: 11.50       Imports: 0.06        Nov: 140         Stock: 162.56      
Production: 11.50       Imports: 0.06        Nov: 1,156       Stock: 499.34      
Production: 1,361.22    Imports: 187.74      Nov: 950         Stock: 661.90      
Production: 1,095.50    Imports: 171.31      Nov: 2,106       Stock: 44.15       
Production: 384.39      Imports: 2.93        Nov: 1,014       Stock: 488.61      
Production: 976.83      Imports: 184.81      Nov: 4.60        Stock: 173.29      
Production: 252.15      Imports: 3.69        Nov: 100.7       Stock: 497.77      
Production: 39.32       Imports: 0.01        Nov: 89.5        Stock: 669.62      
Production: 12.19       Imports: 0.00        Nov: 4.03        Stock: 45.88       
Production: 85.06       Imports: 1.46        Nov: 57.8        Stock: 494.54      
Production: 26.24       Imports: 1.77        Nov: 360.6       Stock: 175.09      
Production: 41.72       Imports: 0.13        Nov: 3.1         Stock: 497.76      
Production: 34.07       Imports: 0.05        Nov: 421.4       Stock: 671.05      
Production: 245.11      Imports: 133.71      Nov: 139.7       Stock: 45.78       
Production: 152.12      Imports: 19.40       Nov: 179.5       Stock: 494.01      
Production: 0.19        Imports: 17.58       Nov: 319.1       Stock: 177.04      
Production: 33.19       Imports: 16.36       Nov: 49.9        Stock: 2,180.98    
Production: 29.07       Imports: 39.13       Nov: 369.0       Stock: 2,875.67    
Production: 0.26        Imports: 11.99       Nov: 52.4        Stock: 320.25      
Production: 30.00       Imports: 14.54       Nov: 5.3         Stock: 2,242.47    
Production: 0.20        Imports: 10.19       Nov: 4.7         Stock: 727.78      
Production: 265.72      Imports: 16.43       Nov: 75.9        Stock: 2,191.07    
Production: 1,396.68    Imports: 199.73      Nov: 64          Stock: 2,911.62    
Production: 1,394.89    Imports: 201.43      Nov: 358         Stock: 345.01      
Production: 1,134.21    Imports: 185.33      Nov: 0           Stock: 2,285.10    
Production: 1,132.41    Imports: 187.03      Nov: 421         Stock: 709.92      
Production: 363.65      Imports: 3.43        Nov: 160         Stock: 2,236.65    
Production: 360.82      Imports: 3.39        Nov: 100         Stock: 2,940.82    
Production: 1,033.03    Imports: 196.30      Nov: 260         Stock: 346.78      
Production: 1,034.06    Imports: 198.05      Nov: 110         Stock: 2,306.25    
Production: 302.69      Imports: 3.03        Nov: 370         Stock: 714.34    
Production: 302.48      Imports: 3.05        Nov: 51          Stock: 2,239.15    
Production: 57.73       Imports: 0.01        Nov: 3.40        Stock: 2,941.47    
Production: 57.63       Imports: 0.01        Nov: 277.90      Stock: 349.26      
Production: 11.50       Imports: 0.00        Nov: 765.55      Stock: 2,309.22    
Production: 11.00       Imports: 0.00        Nov: 176.53      Stock: 711.00      
Production: 104.23      Imports: 1.70        Nov: 148.47      Stock: 714.93      
Production: 104.35      Imports: 1.70        Nov: 755.17      Stock: 941.22      
Production: 28.56       Imports: 1.03        Nov: 180.68      Stock: 157.81      
Production: 28.56       Imports: 1.03        Nov: 288.28      Stock: 713.06      
Production: 39.88       Imports: 0.09        Nov: 138.13      Stock: 252.82      
Production: 40.38       Imports: 0.09        Nov: 633.55      Stock: 679.98      
Production: 46.20       Imports: 0.03        Nov: 173.33      Stock: 929.12      
Production: 46.04       Imports: 0.03        Nov: 127.47      Stock: 147.41      
Production: 256.34      Imports: 144.88      Nov: 627.17      Stock: 706.09      
Production: 253.80      Imports: 146.05      Nov: 179.38      Stock: 248.51      
Production: 158.75      Imports: 22.01       Nov: 142.61      Stock: 711.84      
Production: 158.55      Imports: 22.01       Nov: 29.39       Stock: 956.87      
Production: 0.18        Imports: 17.37       Nov: 52.26       Stock: 153.82      
Production: 0.18        Imports: 17.77       Nov: 3.27        Stock: 723.32      
Production: 33.10       Imports: 18.01       Nov: 3.81        Stock: 259.40      
Production: 30.60       Imports: 18.16       Nov: 31.46       Stock: 713.29      
Production: 32.81       Imports: 42.92       Nov: 25.86       Stock: 958.54      
Production: 32.96       Imports: 42.24       Nov: 27.59       Stock: 154.82      
Production: 0.25        Imports: 12.51       Nov: 248.51      Stock: 723.71      
Production: 0.27        Imports: 12.51       Nov: 713.29      Stock: 260.68      
Production: 30.96       Imports: 17.26       Nov: 173.27      Stock: 976.83      
Production: 30.96       Imports: 18.26       Nov: 144.66      Stock: 1,297.72    
Production: 0.20        Imports: 10.61       Nov: 723.71      Stock: 118.08      
Production: 0.20        Imports: 10.91       Nov: 154.82      Stock: 1,051.55    
Production: 262.48      Imports: 14.40       Nov: 260.68      Stock: 313.33      
Production: 262.48      Imports: 14.40       Nov: 32.21       Stock: 1,018.87    
Production: 1,080.02    Imports: 149.96      Nov: 326.20      Stock: 1,329.57    
Production: 820.94      Imports: 146.50      Nov: 6.66        Stock: 156.41      
Production: 371.10      Imports: 0.92        Nov: 85.85       Stock: 1,094.98    
Production: 708.92      Imports: 149.05      Nov: 200.45      Stock: 289.54      
Production: 164.42      Imports: 1.18        Nov: 131.00      Stock: 1,033.03    
Production: 32.00       Imports: 0.01        Nov: 33.62       Stock: 1,322.68    
Production: 82.00       Imports: 0.92        Nov: 1.93        Stock: 150.10      
Production: 13.20       Imports: 0.05        Nov: 20.00       Stock: 1,092.55    
Production: 13.10       Imports: 0.17        Nov: 0.01        Stock: 281.03      
Production: 24.12       Imports: 0.04        Nov: 0.05        Stock: 1,034.06    
Production: 126.08      Imports: 88.35       Nov: 6.05        Stock: 1,320.21    
Production: 6.40        Imports: 9.46        Nov: 14.00       Stock: 151.67      
Production: 62.02       Imports: 18.47       Nov: 1.89        Stock: 1,095.67    
Production: 0.00        Imports: 15.67       Nov: 4.96        Stock: 274.43      
Production: 27.57       Imports: 16.13       Nov: 17.20       Stock: 489.23    
Production: 29.95       Imports: 14.20       Nov: 0.15        Stock: 636.73      
Production: 0.07        Imports: 10.02       Nov: 5.00        Stock: 44.37       
Production:             Imports:             Nov: 8.50        Stock: 477.87      
Production: 14.10       Imports: 1.70        Nov: 9.00        Stock: 161.63      
Production: 259.07      Imports: 3.46        Nov: 4.81        Stock: 492.22      
Production: 1,104.01    Imports: 166.09      Nov: 5.92        Stock: 652.93      
Production: 1,102.16    Imports: 167.44      Nov: 33.00       Stock: 41.18       
Production: 850.01      Imports: 159.09      Nov: 0.45        Stock: 484.03      
Production: 848.16      Imports: 160.44      Nov: 4.50        Stock: 171.87      
Production: 350.01      Imports: 1.27        Nov: 9.50        Stock: 491.78      
Production: 347.01      Imports: 1.27        Nov: 24.50       Stock: 661.27      
Production: 754.00      Imports: 164.82      Nov: 5.37        Stock: 42.86       
Production: 755.16      Imports: 166.17      Nov: 10.00       Stock: 490.38      
Production: 214.50      Imports: 1.17        Nov: 153.00      Stock: 173.91      
Production: 214.50      Imports: 1.17        Nov: 5.50        Stock: 491.79      
Production: 50.00       Imports: 0.01        Nov: 56.00       Stock: 662.72      
Production: 50.00       Imports: 0.01        Nov: 127.50      Stock: 42.76       
Production: 101.00      Imports: 1.00        Nov: 29.00       Stock: 489.85      
Production: 101.00      Imports: 1.00        Nov: 12.00       Stock: 175.89      
Production: 13.50       Imports: 0.04        Nov: 7.82        Stock: 580.77      
Production: 14.00       Imports: 0.04        Nov: 74.00       Stock: 690.45      
Production: 14.00       Imports: 0.10        Nov: 0.48        Stock: 176.30      
Production: 14.00       Imports: 0.10        Nov: 17.00       Stock: 484.13      
Production: 36.00       Imports: 0.02        Nov: 39.50       Stock: 116.52      
Production: 35.50       Imports: 0.02        Nov: 34.50       Stock: 596.69      
Production: 129.27      Imports: 95.80       Nov: 8.29        Stock: 713.20      
Production: 127.03      Imports: 97.20       Nov: 1.59        Stock: 171.18      
Production: 6.40        Imports: 10.20       Nov: 29.00       Stock: 489.90      
Production: 6.40        Imports: 9.90        Nov: 0.08        Stock: 127.77      
Production: 64.80       Imports: 21.00       Nov: 3.30        Stock: 574.85      
Production: 64.56       Imports: 21.00       Nov: 9.40        Stock: 703.02      
Production: 0.00        Imports: 15.60       Nov: 20.00       Stock: 172.38      
Production: 0.00        Imports: 16.00       Nov: 1.26        Stock: 498.21      
Production: 27.00       Imports: 17.50       Nov: 182.10      Stock: 109.75      
Production: 25.00       Imports: 17.50       Nov: 203.29      Stock: 571.30      
Production: 30.91       Imports: 16.90       Nov: 115.49      Stock: 699.06      
Production: 30.91       Imports: 17.90       Nov: 39.66       Stock: 172.55      
Production: 0.08        Imports: 10.50       Nov: 299.72      Stock: 494.66      
Production: 0.08        Imports: 10.80       Nov: 13.05       Stock: 109.99      
Production: 14.00       Imports: 1.00        Nov: 188.11      Stock: 331.71      
Production: 14.00       Imports: 1.00        Nov: 0.94        Stock: 349.08      
Production: 254.00      Imports: 7.00        Nov: 1.10        Stock: 89.12       
Production: 254.00      Imports: 7.00        Nov: 6.00        Stock: 328.60      
Production: 494.88      Imports: 46.70       Nov: 0.30        Stock: 16.56       
Production: 346.01      Imports: 41.20       Nov: 7.20        Stock: 333.79      
Production: 5.66        Imports: 0.87        Nov: 0.00        Stock: 350.34      
Production: 489.23      Imports: 45.83       Nov: 0.84        Stock: 93.42       
Production: 181.69      Imports: 0.76        Nov: 1.06        Stock: 331.69      
Production: 13.20       Imports: 0.01        Nov: 5.30        Stock: 14.88       
Production: 112.76      Imports: 0.00        Nov: 7.70        Stock: 340.32      
Production: 7.50        Imports: 0.00        Nov: 0.50        Stock: 355.04      
Production: 20.58       Imports: 0.25        Nov: 12.20       Stock: 94.21       
Production: 27.66       Imports: 0.50        Nov: 0.60        Stock: 338.20      
Production: 241.09      Imports: 21.35       Nov: 1.26        Stock: 14.27       
Production: 148.87      Imports: 5.50        Nov: 139.77      Stock: 337.76      
Production: 2.01        Imports: 2.01        Nov: 132.00      Stock: 352.64      
Production: 37.00       Imports: 2.35        Nov: 3.20        Stock: 93.64     
Production: 4.73        Imports: 2.00        Nov: 21.00       Stock: 336.39      
Production: 12.24       Imports: 1.30        Nov: 128.00      Stock: 13.79       
Production: 2.22        Imports: 3.62        Nov: 1.30        Stock: 198.67      
Production:             Imports:             Nov: 145.67      Stock: 219.33      
Production: 8.20        Imports: 0.56        Nov: 0.97        Stock: 79.87       
Production: 1.64        Imports: 1.66        Nov: 0.95        Stock: 192.25      
Production: 4.30        Imports: 0.09        Nov: 5.90        Stock: 22.22       
Production: 7.79        Imports: 0.69        Nov: 0.70        Stock: 203.24      
Production: 0.18        Imports: 0.81        Nov: 6.50        Stock: 225.46      
Production: 3.97        Imports: 0.40        Nov: 0.28        Stock: 86.19       
Production: 497.77      Imports: 43.85       Nov: 1.04        Stock: 200.14      
Production: 497.76      Imports: 43.35       Nov: 15.46       Stock: 21.09       
Production: 351.77      Imports: 40.75       Nov: 18.87       Stock: 207.50      
Production: 351.76      Imports: 40.85       Nov: 27.40       Stock: 228.78      
Production: 5.99        Imports: 0.94        Nov: 2.25        Stock: 88.61       
Production: 5.97        Imports: 0.94        Nov: 46.75       Stock: 205.21      
Production: 491.78      Imports: 42.91       Nov: 0.89        Stock: 19.66       
Production: 491.79      Imports: 42.41       Nov: 14.09       Stock: 206.47      
Production: 183.60      Imports: 0.66        Nov: 0.20        Stock: 227.55      
Production: 184.60      Imports: 0.66        Nov: 0.06        Stock: 88.69       
Production: 13.30       Imports: 0.01        Nov: 5.10        Stock: 204.54      
Production: 13.30       Imports: 0.01        Nov: 0.05        Stock: 19.09       
Production: 114.00      Imports: 0.00        Nov: 4.76        Stock: 46.1        
Production: 115.00      Imports: 0.00        Nov: 0.40        Stock: 47.8        
Production: 7.50        Imports: 0.00        Nov: 0.20        Stock: 45.2        
Production: 7.50        Imports: 0.00        Nov: 11.77       Stock: 45.2        
Production: 20.50       Imports: 0.25        Nov: 22.68       Stock: 37.6        
Production: 20.50       Imports: 0.25        Nov: 17.09       Stock: 39.6        
Production: 28.30       Imports: 0.40        Nov: 3.92        Stock: 38.1        
Production: 28.30       Imports: 0.40        Nov: 39.04       Stock: 37.2        
Production: 241.70      Imports: 16.03       Nov: 0.72        Stock: 46.4        
Production: 240.60      Imports: 15.43       Nov: 11.78       Stock: 47.6        
Production: 146.00      Imports: 3.10        Nov: 4.92        Stock: 51.6        
Production: 146.00      Imports: 2.50        Nov: 0.00        Stock: 51.7        
Production: 2.01        Imports: 2.05        Nov: 27.10       Stock: 1,181       
Production: 2.01        Imports: 2.05        Nov: 8.04        Stock: 1,099       
Production: 37.40       Imports: 0.60        Nov: 25.82       Stock: 1,080       
Production: 36.50       Imports: 1.40        Nov: 1.07        Stock: 1,080       
Production: 4.90        Imports: 2.20        Nov: 5.14        Stock: 1,741       
Production: 4.90        Imports: 1.80        Nov: 16.99       Stock: 1,885       
Production: 12.20       Imports: 2.70        Nov: 102.19      Stock: 1,962       
Production: 12.00       Imports: 2.50        Nov: 0.02        Stock: 1,920       
Production: 2.29        Imports: 3.68        Nov: 6.00        Stock: 158
Production: 2.29        Imports: 3.68        Nov: 98.00       Stock: 135
Production: 7.14        Imports: 1.10        Nov: 0.50        Stock: 120
Production: 7.14        Imports: 1.10        Nov: 20.70       Stock: 120
Production: 1.55        Imports: 1.90        Nov: 1.68        Stock: 3,080       
Production: 1.55        Imports: 2.00        Nov: 11.50       Stock: 3,119       
Production: 4.30        Imports: 0.30        Nov: 0.06        Stock: 3,161       
Production: 4.30        Imports: 0.30        Nov: 1.80        Stock: 3,120       
Production: 7.80        Imports: 0.69        Nov: 6.60        Stock: 964
Production: 7.80        Imports: 0.69        Nov: 5.20        Stock: 955
Production: 0.20        Imports: 0.79        Nov: 1.44        Stock: 960
Production: 0.20        Imports: 0.79        Nov: 347.30      Stock: 955
Production: 3.88        Imports: 0.41        Nov: 1,394.89    Stock: 63
Production: 3.88        Imports: 0.41        Nov: 201.43      Stock: 59
```

Comment: Great. You code solution seems to work fine, and it 's faster than the one i was using. And speed it's very important for my project. Thank you

Comment: @Davide you welcome, glad to help :P upvote if you liked

Answer (score 0):

The code below uses python ElementTree lib to read 'Data1' and 'Data3'.

since the XML is very big I am not sure those results are correct but if it is - you can extend it and use it for 'Data2' and 'Data4',

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = requests.get('https://www.usda.gov/oce/commodity/wasde/wasde1119.xml').content.decode('utf-8')
root = ET.fromstring(xml)

# Data1
cells = root.findall(".//sr19//matrix1//m1_month_group[@forecast_month1='Oct']//m1_attribute_group[@attribute1='Production']//Cell")
values = [cell.attrib['cell_value1'] for cell in cells]
print(values)

# Data3
cells = root.findall(".//sr11//matrix1//attribute1[@attribute1='Yield per Harvested Acre']//m1_month_group[@forecast_month1='Nov']//Cell")
values = [cell.attrib['cell_value1'] for cell in cells]
print(values)
```

output

```
['765.23', '633.23', '53.39', '711.84', '324.70', '20.50', '18.00', '33.00', '152.00', '72.50', '28.70', '203.07', '1.10', '5.30', '132.00', '0.95', '18.87', '0.06', '22.46', '0.00', '102.19', '11.50']
['51.7']
```

Comment: Thanks. I never tired to use etree before but I have read that it is better for xml pages than BeautifulSoup. I will give it a try.